# Trouble adding domain name

Tags: virtualization, host

I've added a new virtual host configuration to my stuff, I copied a configuration file for a live site that works, modified the 7 lines that it is and then `a2ensite`  it, added it to /etc/hosts and it's not functioning.  Google chrome is saying that it simply couldn't find the domain name, I'm wondering if it's even connected to my server.  But I also duplicated the `*`, `@`, and `www` records to point to my server.

```
<VirtualHost 64.253.105.250:80>
        -- REMOVED --

        DocumentRoot /home/benkuhl/public_html/

        ErrorLog /home/benkuhl/log/error_log
        TransferLog /home/benkuhl/log/access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there some place I'm missing to modify a file or something... I'm using enom as my domain host.  I feel like I'm missing something on apache...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to test this by adding it to `/etc/hosts` before creating an actual DNS record for the domain? From what I can see, neither `www.benkuhl.com` nor `benkuhl.com` have valid A or CNAME records.

If you're trying to test via `/etc/hosts`, then did you edit this file on your client or on the server? For testing purposes, you'd need to edit your client's hosts file, not the server's.

Comment: What do you mean testing via /etc/hosts ?  It's my understanding that I have to have the domain listed or it won't work.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. It sounds like you just need to create DNS records for www.benkuhl.com and benkuhl.com, pointing to your server's IP. After doing that, you'll be good.

Comment: Those DNS records already exist, I've contacted enom to figure out what's up....

Answer (score 1):

i'd rather have commented on the question but with only 16 rep i cannot do that

i'm curious about you nslookup output